# Local declaration of X hides instance of variable

Tags: objective-c

Why do i get local declaration of eID hides instance of variable warning in xcode?

```
NSString *eID = [entertainmentArticle objectForKey:@"eID"];


   NSURL *urlScheduleDetailsView = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mydomain.com/iostest/appPHPs/scheduleView.php?eID=%@",eID]];
```

Comment: Please look at all of the related questions to yours. This error has been covered many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may have declared a var with the same name somewhere else as a global (class?) declaration...